# Is there a way to a regex query on a json structure's keys?

Tags: ruby, json

Say I have I have a list of json structure such as

> `{ "S1" => "foo", "R2" => "bar", "S2" => "baz" }`

and I want to get the data for the "S*" keys,

How would you do that in ruby? Is there any way to perform such a task?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) to pick out the key/value pairs you want:

```
{ "S1" => "foo", "R2" => "bar", "S2" => "baz" }.select{|k,v| k =~ /^S/}
```

The result is the desired hash - if you are using Ruby 1.9/2.0.  However, in Ruby 1.8 this will return an array of arrays - you can wrap this with `Hash[]` to turn it back to a hash:

```
start = { "S1" => "foo", "R2" => "bar", "S2" => "baz" }
Hash[start.select{|k,v| k =~ /^S/}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have already parsed json to hash it can be done in this way:

```
{ "S1" => "foo", "R2" => "bar", "S2" => "baz" }.select {|k,v| k.match /^S.*/}
```

If this is still json, you will have to use JSON.parse before.

```
require "json"
JSON.parse(your_json)
```

Comment: The `.*` would seem to be extraneous here...  good point about parsing the JSON string, I had taken that as a given.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I gave the answer credit to PinnyM since he was the first to respond.

Comment: yes, PinnyM regex was also better then mine before I corrected it :)